# replacing dependent random variables with independent random variables.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have $x$ and $y$ independent sub-Gaussian random variables and the quadratic form:
$z= x^2+xy$

Let $x'$ be an independent and identically distributed copy of $x$. If I use the replacement
$z'= x^2+x'y$

How can I compare $z$ and $z'$ (if any comparison exists)?

Thank you

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ independent?

Comment: yes, x and y are independent.